# Is Sasuke serious about rebuilding the Uchiha clan?

Tags: naruto

Is Sasuke actually serious about ever restoring his clan?

Restoring the Uchiha clan, both in population and prestige, was the second of Sasuke's two major life goals since the beginning of the *Naruto* series. Yet by 700, some 20 years after the massacre, he has so far succeeded in producing only a single Uchiha heir. If we include Sakura, that's only 2 additional Uchiha in that entire time! Given the highly dangerous shinobi training regime and overall risky lifestyle, isn't it  reckless to rely on Sarada alone to carry the tribal line, especially given the number of children he'd need to create a [minimal viable population (MVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_population): sustainability levels for vertibrate mammals is generally estimated at 500 to 1000 individuals, but given there's a whole village of Konoha to interbreed with, let's be generous and say only 5% of that number would be needed (25-35). If so, then Sasuke really should be having in the order of 12 children (who, if each of those keeps up near that birthrate, the Uchiha clan would be fully restored within 2-3 generations!) I know it's common for contemporary Japanese families to produce only one or two children at most, so it's what the readers would be used to, but this is ancient/different dimension Japan!

What exactly is he waiting for?

(Maybe Shin will have to step up to the plate instead, or Orochimaru making a ton of test tube Uchiha babies, haha!)

Comment: You might have missed that whole story, Sasuke's aim was never been to produce more uchiha at all. But to take revenge and then to take more revenge and then to stand on his side with naruto.

Comment: On that first point, I refer you to chaps 4, 225, Shippuden anime S06E24, etc. Secondly, resurrection of the Uchiha clan to its previous position of honor as a vital (and respected) component of Konoha society, was always an element of the whole redemption arc for the whole bunch of Uchiha (resolving the troubles started by Madara and then later Obito). You can't do that if the Uchiha are left as only one or two (which may well go extinct within 1-2 more generations!)